# Default type for Unions

Tags: c, unions

I've heard that some compilers allows the following:

```
union {
   int array[2]; // The default type for this union is `int[2]`
   struct {
      int low;
      int high;
   } word;
} foo;


// Normal usage
foo.a[0] = 0; 
foo.low = 0

// What I am looking for
foo[0] = 0;
```

Is it part of the C99/C11 standards?

**EDIT**

I think I've found what was making me confused. We can actually declare an union without name in C.

```
struct {
   union {
      int all[2];
      struct {
         int low;
         int high;
      } word;
   } bar;
} foo;

foo.bar.all[0];
foo.bar.low;
foo.bar.high;
```

In that particular case It solves my XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not part of standard C.

If any compilers support it (I'm not sure offhand, as I've never sought to use such a feature) it will be a vendor-specific extension.

It is possible in C++ for a union to have an `operator[]()`, but there is no equivalent in C.   The only time I saw it used, I had to resist temptation to strangle the programmer.

Comment: I've edited my question I think I was confused of what my real problem was.